# Не могу понять, как между then предается Promise, когда еще не выполнен даже главный

Tags: javascript, node.js

Знаю если кратко, что каждый `then()`, возвращает новый промис, а следующий за ним по цепочке `then()` извлекает результат из этого промиса. Но есть недопонимание как передается этот результат другому `then()`, если еще первый `Promise` не выполнился, а цепочка `then()` может быть большая.

Наверно есть место куда помещаются все обработчики из каждого `.then()` или же каким-то образом строится что-то на подобии рекурсии из промисов, где каждый выполнившийся промис запускает следующий, если это так, то должно быть специальная свойство для этого, а может еще есть какой-то не известный мне механизм, я бы хотел узнать об этом по подробнее.

Первый мой пример, подтверждает больше теорию о рекурсивности Promise. В консоли браузера, то там будет видно что промис возвращается сразу же, а уже потом выполняется все остальное.

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("test result");
        reject("test error")
    }, 1000);
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Обычная операция " + result);
    return result;
}).then(function(result) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Асинхронная операция " + result);
            resolve(result);
        }, 1000);

    });
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Обычная операция " + result);
    return result;
}).catch(function(error) {
    throw error;
});
```

А вот второй пример, как-то слабо её подтверждает. Так как если начальную точку сделать синхронной,то промис возвращается почему после срабатывания 1-го `console.log()`, хотя по логике он должен был бы вернуться в самом начале.

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("test result");
    reject("test error");
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Обычная операция " + result);
    return result;
}).then(function(result) {    
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Асинхронная операция " + result);
            resolve(result);
        }, 1000);
    });
}).then(function(result) {
    console.log("Обычная операция " + result);
    return result;
}).catch(function(error) {
    throw error;
});
```

Собственно раз есть такое непредсказуемое поведения, я и решил разобраться в этом поподробнее, но пока сам ответа не нашел, поэтому прошу помощи у вас.

Предупреждаю, чтобы наверняка увидеть различия этих двух примеров их нужно выполнить строго в консоли Chrome!

Comment: вам нужно почитать про цикл событий. Там вы найдете ответы на все ваши вопросы (плюс на десерт почему промисы нельзя в трай кетч помещать). В ответ такой объем текста не влезет... ну или будет не полным

Comment: например https://habrahabr.ru/company/ruvds/blog/340508/

Comment: torokhkun, да я в курсе про event loop, когда-то я плохо понимал как он работает, но потом наткнулся на этот материал он хорошо мне расставил точки над и https://youtu.be/8cV4ZvHXQL4. После этого все хорошо ложилось в эту картину, пока я не добрался до промисов. Но опять же меня именно интересуют как так передаётся результат одному обработчику .then к другому .then обработчику.

Comment: Сам это вопрос у меня возник при прочтении этой статьи http://learn.javascript.ru/promise#промисы-в-деталях. Там в крации написано что в зависимости от PromiseState, образчики в .then подаются либо "PromiseJobs" что практически = принципу event loop, либо в PromiseFulfillReactions и PromiseRejectReactions. Но вот уж сколько я её не перечитывал так и не смог понять, как между этими обработчиками предается результат, написано только что возвращается новый промис с результатом, а потом другой .then его извлекает и предает своим обработчикам.

Comment: Вот мне как раз интересен сам этот процесс когда .then понимает что его нужно извлечь, какой механизм для этого используются?

Если б все было бы синхронно, я бы без проблем понял, но при асинхронности как-то непонятно, как он может что-то вернуть если он находится "PromiseJobs", обработчики там должны как-то сообщаться между собой иначе они не перейдут результат друг другу.

Comment: Сейчас у меня освободилось время, решил прочесть статью по той ссылке, на всякий случай, там все примерно тоже самое чего-то даже нет, например про "PromiseJobs" + я узнал несколько интересных вещей для себя, но опять же там не описан полностью весь процесс передачи результата между обработчиками в .then-ах, то есть ответа я там на свои вопросы так и не нашел.